# error: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, sqldatatypes

I am creating tables based on the SQL Developer, however, got couple problems from my code:

My table can be established one by one, but cannot run as a whole and get error:

> ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

When I am trying to insert values, get the error:

> ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column

I have no idea about how these two error come from and everything look like fine on my code.

```
create table FACULTY (
faculty_id  VARCHAR(25),
fac_name    VARCHAR(25),
office      VARCHAR(25),
salary      NUMBER(9,2),
primary key (faculty_id)
)

create table student (
student_id  VARCHAR(25),
std_name    VARCHAR(25),
home_phone  CHAR(12),
total_credits   NUMBER,
gpa         NUMBER(1,2),
advisor_id  VARCHAR(25),
PRIMARY KEY (student_id),
foreign key (advisor_id) REFERENCES FACULTY (faculty_id)
)
```

INSERT INTO student table, I have already insert values successfully for FACULTY table;

```
insert into student
values('111111111', 'Marcus', '21-4748363', 0, 3.11, '90421');
```

For 1st question:

```
Error report -
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
00922. 00000 -  "missing or invalid option"
```

For 2nd question:

```
Error starting at line : 40 in command -
insert into student
values('111111111', 'Marcus', '21-4748363', 0, 3.11, '90421')
Error report -
ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
```

Comment: Which dialect of SQL?

Comment: in the students table you have created gpa as a number(1,2) which means that it has a total of 1 digit and out of this digit 2 are selected as decimals. So to solve the problem of question 2, you should have created this as number(3,2)  and this way it would accept 3 digits and 2 of them would be the decimals.

Comment: @cte6 What an answer... I owe you one! Thx sooo Much

Comment: @nicomp The oracle  sql developer

Comment: ok, got the first job done by adding semicolon after end of each table...

Comment: Unrelated, but: do not use the `char` data type. It has absolutely no advantages whatsoever, but many annoying disadvantages. Use `varchar` instead.

Answer (score 0):

**For 1st question**

Use semicolon `;` after the first table definition.

**For 2nd question**

You should define your table like this:

```sql
create table student (
student_id  VARCHAR(25),
std_name    VARCHAR(25),
home_phone  CHAR(12),
total_credits   NUMBER,
gpa         NUMBER(3,2),
advisor_id  VARCHAR(25),
PRIMARY KEY (student_id),
foreign key (advisor_id) REFERENCES FACULTY (faculty_id)
)
```

For gpa column it should be NUMBER(3,2) instead of NUMBER(1,2) to support 3.11 Value.